# Wordpress htaccess not working with subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

i have directory`offering-pages` in my domain

offering-pages/.htaccess code is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

i access dashboard of wordpress and only the home page of my website.
when i go to other page like `http://domain/offering-pages/offerings-for-students/` it display the content of `domain/index.php`

Comment: Did you accidentally wrote `offering-page` instead of `offering-pages`?

Comment: ya its offering-pages not offering-page

Comment: `RewriteRule ./index.php [L]` - There should be a space between `.` and `/index.php` (otherwise this directive won't do anything helpful). However, this .htaccess file assumes your site is in the document root (doesn't WordPress itself manage this?). If this .htaccess file is in a subdirectory then one way to "fix the .htaccess file" is to remove the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` substitution ie. `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` and remove the `RewriteBase` directive entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script and change domain and subdomain according to their names and also post wordpress related question to [wordpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

```
RewriteEngine On

# rewrite subdomains to separate folder
RewriteRule ^subdomain/ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain/$1 [L]
# or if you want to rewrite sub.domain.com/test to /subdomain/sub/test
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain/%1/$1 [L]

# force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R]


# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Wordpress in the offering-pages directory? If so, you need to change index.php to point to your directory where Wordpress is installed.

From:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-blog-header.php');
```

To:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/offering-pages/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Comment: it not work give error:- failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Comment: You didnt answer my question. Yes or no, did you install Wordpress in another subdirectory different than the root?

Comment: Move the .htaccess file to the root of your website, not in the subdirectory.

Comment: i have moved .htaccess its give :- /index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: You also need to change the Wordpress Address URL to http://www.yoursite.com/offering-pages and the Site Address to http://www.yoursite.com in the Dashboard config

Comment: i have moved index.php and edit to :-require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/offering-pages/wp-blog-header.php');

Comment: its work properly But i have my php webite on root folder and it has already index.php and i have to put wordpress on root/offering-pages

Comment: The modified index.php must be in the root folder of your website. The .htaccess file must be in the root folder of your website. For example, if it is on Apache, the root of your website is something like public_html/yourwebsite

Comment: I have to step away. I wrote about this a few years ago on my website. You can learn more about setting up Wordpress in its own folder here: http://kobashicomputing.com/running-wordpress-on-wamp-server

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!

The top site's custom Permalinks (anything other than "Plain") clash with the subdirectory site's custom Permalinks (anything other than "Plain").

Both cannot be set to be custom (without a complicated solution).

To fix (and not get "Invalid JSON response" when modifying or creating Posts and Pages), simply delete the top site's .htaccess file (in the root directory usually under public_html).

And to prevent future clashes, go to the top site's site Settings > Permalinks in WordPress and change the setting to Plain, delete any Category and Tag Base, and click SAVE.  When you click SAVE, a new .htaccess file is created or the old one is overwritten for that directory (and Plain actually means an empty .htaccess file or no setting).

This means that you won't be creating pages and posts with pretty URLs from the top site (for that specific site you'll have to use an auto-generated post or page url like example.com/?p=123 instead of example.com/postname).

Antonio Robateau